# how to resolve the ''cannot read property 'property-name' of null?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve all the data from firebase database into an array in typescript. Here is the relevant code snippet :

```js
export class ViewUserPage {
  public list = [];
  public ref = firebase.database().ref();
  public usersRef = this.ref.child('users');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}
  
  ionViewDidLoad(){
  
  this.usersRef.orderByChild('tag').equalTo('staff').on('child_added',function(snap){
    this.list.push(snap.val());console.log(snap.val());
    });

}

   

}
```

The error I'm getting is this "Cannot read property 'list' of null". I think it is occurring in the

```js
this.usersRef.orderByChild('tag').equalTo('staff').on('child_added',function(snap){
    this.list.push(snap.val());console.log(snap.val());
```

part. This is the full error:

```html
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of null
    at main.js:59030
    at main.js:30999
    at fc (main.js:30861)
    at bf (main.js:30926)
    at cf (main.js:30925)
    at Qg.g.Gb (main.js:31016)
    at Ag.g.wd (main.js:30980)
    at og.wd (main.js:30970)
    at Yf.Xf (main.js:30968)
    at ag (main.js:30952)
defaultErrorLogger @ main.js:1436
```

How to go about this ? Please help !

Comment: can paste your html where are you using list variable in template?

Comment: add your full error image which might include function name or anything else related to error

Comment: @RahulSingh i haven't used the list array in html yet. Here I am just trying to store the elements in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `function` keyword which creates a new scope and changes value of `this`, you should use fat arrow functions instead which don't change the value of `this`, but as per your comments `firebase` seems to bind another value for `this` so you need to store value of `this` in another variable like below:

```
let that = this;
this.usersRef.orderByChild('tag').equalTo('staff').on('child_added', (snap) => {
    that.list.push(snap.val());
    console.log(snap.val());
});
```

Comment: This worked to a certain extent, as in the previous error got resolved. Now I am getting a new error which says : '' TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined '' . How do I get around this ?

Comment: maybe firebase is changing value of `this`, so i am storing value of `this` in another variable `that`, i have edited my answer, let me know if this new solution works

Comment: do u confirm `public list = [];` still exists in your code

Comment: I had changed it to "public list:string[];" hence it wasn't working. When i changed it back, it worked ! Any idea why so ?

Comment: When u wrote `public list: string[];` it just tells typescript that in future this variable will hold an array of strings but the value is still `undefined`. What you need to do is initialize an empty array like this: `public list: string[] = [];`